# Testing a Flask application with a DB: SQLite alterntive with schema

Tags: python, database, unit-testing, sqlalchemy

I want to test a Flask application that has a database in my CI pipeline. I wanted to replace the database for testing by SQLite because SQLite does not need any setup.

However, the tables have a schema and schema is not supported by SQLite. Is there another lightweight database that does have schema support? Preferably also a file-based one or an in-memory one which does not need initial setup?

### Minimal Example

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "sqlite:///foobar.db"

Base = declarative_base()
user = sa.Table(
    "users", Base.metadata, sa.Column("id", sa.Integer, primary_key=True), schema="foobar"
)

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

gives

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "foobar"
[SQL: PRAGMA "foobar".table_info("users")]
```

Comment: I have the same problem ... do you find a workaround ? thank you

Comment: No - well, except if you count using a DB in a dev environment and having an integration test instead of an unit test.